# Angular 5 FormGroup Validator Expected validator to return Promise or Observable

Tags: angular

My FormGroup validator raises the "Promise or Observable" error. I've studied many SO examples explaining to return an Observable or Promise as the error states, but none explain why a return of null works fine in the web service calling block, but not at the end of the validator function, if it drops through to the bottom.

The validator is working fine. It's just that I'd like to eliminate the error when getting started.

component.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.dnFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    displayName: ['', [Validators.required], this.validateDisplayName.bind(this)] //NOTE: 2nd option is required! See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#description
    }); 
}

public validateDisplayName(control: AbstractControl) {
    if(control.value.length >= 3 && control.value !== this.authService.displayName) {
        this.displayName = control.value;

        return this.authService.validateDisplayName(control.value).then( 
           (res) => {
            if(res) {
              //displayName already used
              return { displayNameTaken: true };              
            } else {
              //displayName can be used
              return null;
            }
          },
          (err) => {
            return { displayNameTaken: true };                            
       });      
    }
    return null;  //<<<<< ERROR "Expected validator to return Promise or Observable"
}
```

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know much about validators, but **only the type of the first return** in your function will matter.

In the if block, you return a Promise (that returns either `null` or an object but it's not important) so it's OK.

But outside the block, you just return `null`, that is neither a Promise nor an object. Try to make it a Promise that returns `null` (with `return Promise.resolve(null)`) or an Observable that returns `null` (with `import { of } from 'rxjs';` and `return of(null)`).